# Regular expression to match non-www and non-specified host (nginx)

Tags: nginx, regular-expressions

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     ~(?!^www\.)(?!thehost.org);
    return 301      $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

I'd like for the server_name to match otherhost.org and differenthost.org, and then return a 301 to www.otherhost.org and www.differenthost.org, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    servername ~^(?<domain>otherhost|differenthost)\.org$;
    return 301 $scheme://www.$domain.org$request_uri;
}
```